# How to follow the edges backwards of directed graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create the code to follow the edges backwards of graph to construct the subgraph from target graph(directed).

For better explanation, I drew an example.
[image: here is the example.]

First, randomly select the initial node from target graph.(colored green in example figure)

Then, I want to get "backwards" neighbor nodes set of initial node.(possible "backwards" neighbor nodes are encircled by red line)

Here is the code that extract subgraph from directed graph. In this subgraph constructiing process,　neighbor nodes are taken according to the direction of the edges.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def RWS(G, r=0.5, S=4):
    #initialize subgraph
    Gk = nx.DiGraph()
    #initialize nodes 
    Vk = [] 
    #randomly select the initial node from G
    vs = np.random.randint(0, G.size()) 
    print(vs)
    #add vs to Gk
    Gk.add_node(vs) 
    Vk.append(vs)

    while len(Vk) < S:
        #get neighbor nodes set of Vk (step 4) (Also appending j just for the purpose of adding edge)
        NS = [(n, j) for j in Vk for n in G.neighbors(j) if n not in Vk]
        print("{} {} {} {}".format('length of NS is', len(NS), 'and vs =', vs))
        # randomly select r of nodes in NS, add them into the Vk
        if not len(NS) == 0:
            for node, j in NS:
                if np.random.uniform() < r:
                    Vk.append(node)
                    Gk.add_edge(j, node)
                    if len(Vk) == S or len(NS) < S:
                        break
        else:
            break
    return Gk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # "Undirected" graph adjacency matrix
    m = np.matrix([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

    # G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(m, create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())
    G =  nx.from_numpy_matrix(m, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
    #expansion ratio
    r  = 0.5
    #subgraph size
    S  = 4

    Gk = RWS(G, r, S)

    # VISUALIZATION
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=list(Gk.nodes()), node_color='r')
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color='b', width=0.5)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=list(Gk.edges()), edge_color='g', width=1, arrowstyle='->')

    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Yes, you already understand that I want to do the opposite of this code, to get subgraph of the backwards neighbor nodes.

maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63534977/how-to-get-neighbor-nodes) of mine will be helpful for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your algorithm with minimal modifications by

1. Running it with the reversed graph. You can reverse a graph with [DiGraph.reverse](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.reverse.html). In your case, you could perform `Gi = G.reverse()` and use that instead of `G` in `RWS`;
2. Reversing the result, again with `DiGraph.reverse`.

A modified implementation of `RWS` could look like this:

```py
def RWS(G, r=0.5, S=4):
    #initialize subgraph
    Gk = nx.DiGraph()
    #initialize nodes 
    Vk = [] 
    #randomly select the initial node from G
    vs = np.random.randint(0, G.size()) 
    print(vs)
    #add vs to Gk
    Gk.add_node(vs) 
    Vk.append(vs)
    Gi = G.reverse()  # reverse input graph so we can just follow the edges
    while len(Vk) < S:
        #get neighbor nodes set of Vk (step 4) (Also appending j just for the purpose of adding edge)
        NS = [(n, j) for j in Vk for n in Gi.neighbors(j) if n not in Vk]
        print("{} {} {} {}".format('length of NS is', len(NS), 'and vs =', vs))
        # randomly select r of nodes in NS, add them into the Vk
        if not len(NS) == 0:
            for node, j in NS:
                if np.random.uniform() < r:
                    Vk.append(node)
                    Gk.add_edge(j, node)
                    if len(Vk) == S or len(NS) < S:
                        break
        else:
            break
    return Gk.reverse()  # Reverse result
```